# CSS - Issue with stretched background image (Samsung Mobile)

Tags: css

I don't know if the Samsung default "Internet Browser" is based on another build but it's not displaying stretched background images correctly like on desktop browser or chrome for mobile.

I'm using this CSS and HTML

```
#bk_img {

    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;


    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


<img src="background.jpg" id="bk_img">
```

When scrolling down a white area appears below the background image, about 30px high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height: auto;` will resize the image aspect ration based on `width:100%`. Probably you have your image resized but because you have a scrollbar, the height will be resized accordingly to width:100% and aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's some margin or padding which the browser sets by default. Does this work?:

```
#bk_img {
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
html, body, img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

<img src="http://sublantic.net/forge/demos/img/code_canyon/scale.png" id="bk_img">
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Q4U3/